# Can't find Command Prompt in Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-prompt

Trying to choose Command Prompt in the Terminal however I can only see Zsh, bash, and Javascript bug terminal.... I've gone in to Select Default profile as suggested in similar threads I've found and still can't find it?

How do i get Command Prompt in there?

Note: I don't have Powershell either, and I'm on a Mac

Comment: "Ctrl+`" brings the built-in terminal of the vs code and it uses the default shell of your operating system. In Unix based systems, Bash and other shells work instead of cmd.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Why do you expect or need the Windows Command Prompt or Powershell on a Mac? The bash option should be fine on a Mac. You might want to re-read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `cmd.exe`, that is a windows only program and you won't be able to use it on MacOS.

Terminal is the MacOS Equivalent and can run shells such as `bash` and `zsh` as you noted.